# Firebase Admin SDK Not Reading, Writing, or Throwing Errors (Node.js)

Tags: firebase, heroku, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

This question was previously closed, telling me to "update the question so it focuses on one problem only;" I don't *know* what the problem is, and if I did, I wouldn't be posting this question. Regardless, I'll make some clarifications here:

1. I was previously using just the normal Firebase module (the one imported using "npm i firebase"); everything worked perfectly before. The issue has to do with the authentication (as far as I am aware) with the Firebase Admin SDK. I don't understand how I'm supposed to send this to the Heroku build without revealing the service account key JSON file on my GitHub.
2. As for the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path, is there a way where I don't have to set it every session? The Heroku app restarts once a day, and I would need to somehow automate this entry process (or skip it entirely). That's the way I currently understand it. Here's a quote from a previous answer:

> > When I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path, doesn't this only set it on my local machine?

> Environment variables only work on the individual machine and process where they have been set. If you want it set on another machine and process, you will have to arrange for that separately. According to the documentation:

> > Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. **This variable only applies to your current shell session**, so if you open a new session, set the variable again.

3. My main question here is as follows: "I implemented the Firebase Admin SDK incorrectly. How do I do it the right way?"
4. Even just posting a link to guides that would help would be appreciated (although I understand this is typically discouraged as links sometimes break).

---

## Original:

Note: this is my first time using the Firebase Admin SDK, so I'm really not sure what I'm doing (although I have used Firebase quite a bit).

Recently, I decided I would go back to one of my older Discord bots and actually authenticate its requests to Firebase properly (I hadn't done this previously as I've never authenticated from a server before and didn't think it was possible). I discovered the Firebase Admin SDK, which sounded perfect for my needs (the bot is being hosted on Heroku, for the record).

I found this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup, but there's a few things I can't wrap my head around (note that these are purely rhetorical, you don't need to answer them in your answer; I'm just providing them so you can understand my thought process):

- When I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path, doesn't this only set it on my local machine? I could also try running the export command on the server (using "heroku run" in the CLI), but then the path would be pointing to a file that doesn't exist on the server (since the service account key JSON file is on my local machine). Do I need to set an environment variable in Heroku or something?
- How does "admin.credential.applicationDefault()" know how to get the credentials?

I can't find any other guides that make sense.

The way I currently have it setup must be wrong, since reads and writes fail silently.

Firebase setup code:

```
// Setup Firebase:
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize Firebase:
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://<APP>.firebaseio.com" // I removed the actual <APP> name to ask this question
});

let database = admin.database();
```

Things like `database.ref("test").set("Hello World!");` don't change the data in the database, and no errors are thrown (I've also tried attaching a .then and a .catch to the end of this; still nothing). This was working before I switched over to the Firebase Admin SDK (I was just using the "firebase" module previously, rather than the "firebase-admin" module that I'm now using). The same goes for reading data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "answer" you cite is still correct.  It seems you are mostly asking about how to set up environment variables on Heroku.  I would rewrite your question to be more specific about that, as it's not really the admin SDK that you're having problems with.

Comment: @DougStevenson I already know how to setup environment variables; the service account key information is stored in a JSON file.

Comment: OK, the I'm unclear what your question is.  Actually I read two questions in your post - I suggest clarifying it down to a single question that explains what isn't working the way you expect, or where you are stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my problem:

I was sending `res.status(200)` outside of the async firebase call, killing the request before firebase had a chance to finish. Somehow localhost allows this to work properly but when its hosted things go sideways.

so I had this

```
fireabse.database().ref('parent/foo').set('bar');
res.status(200)
```

I needed this:

```
firebase.database().ref('parent/foo').set('bar').then(() => {
   res.status(200);
});
```